# How to scrape multiple pages from a website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

(Very) New to Python and programming in general

I've been trying to scrape data from more pages/section of the same website with Scrapy

My code works, but it's unreadable and not practical

```
import scrapy

class SomeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'some'
    allowed_domains = ['https://example.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://example.com/Python/?k=books&p=1',
        'https://example.com/Python/?k=books&p=2',
        'https://example.com/Python/?k=books&p=3',
        'https://example.com/Python/?k=tutorials&p=1',
        'https://example.com/Python/?k=tutorials&p=2',
        'https://example.com/Python/?k=tutorials&p=3',
     ]

     def parse(self, response):
         response.selector.remove_namespaces()

         info1 = response.css("scrapedinfo1").extract()
         info2 = response.css("scrapedinfo2").extract()

         for item in zip(scrapedinfo1, scrapedinfo2):
           scraped_info = {
              'scrapedinfo1': item[0],
              'scrapedinfo2': item[1]}

              yield scraped_info
```

How can I improve this?

I'd like to search within a certain amount of categories and pages

I need something like

```
categories = [books, tutorials, a, b, c, d, e, f] 
in a range(1,3)
```

So that Scrapy would be able to do its job through all categories and pages, while being easy to edit and adapt to other websites

Any ideas are welcome

What I have tried:

```
categories = ["books", "tutorials"]
base = "https://example.com/Python/?k={category}&p={index}"

def url_generator():
    for category, index in itertools.product(categories, range(1, 4)):
        yield base.format(category=category, index=index)
```

But Scrapy returns

```
[scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), 
scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code on SO.

Comment: `url_generator()` is method inside class  so it need `self` - `def url_generator(self):`, the same with categories - `product( self.categories`, ...). BTW: use `print()` to see what you get with `base.format(category=category, index=index)`

Comment: scrapy has method [start_requests](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) to generate urls at start. And it has to yield `Request(url= ...)` not only string with `url`

Answer (score 1):

Solved thanks to `start_requests()` and `yield scrapy.Request()`

Here's the code

```
import scrapy
import itertools


class SomeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'somespider'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        categories = ["books", "tutorials"]
        base = "https://example.com/Python/?k={category}&p={index}"

        for category, index in itertools.product(categories, range(1, 4)):
            yield scrapy.Request(base.format(category=category, index=index))

    def parse(self, response):
        response.selector.remove_namespaces()

        info1 = response.css("scrapedinfo1").extract()
        info2 = response.css("scrapedinfo2").extract()

        for item in zip(info1, info2):
            scraped_info = {
                'scrapedinfo1': item[0],
                'scrapedinfo2': item[1],
            }

            yield scraped_info
```

Comment: You're correct! I wrote it without double-check! :)

Comment: so I remove my previous comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `start_requests()` to generate urls at start using `yield Request(url)`.

BTW: Later in `parse()` you can also use `yield Request(url)` to add new url.

I use portal [toscrape.com](http://toscrape.com/) which was created for testing spiders.

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    allowed_domains = ['http://quotes.toqoute.com']

    #start_urls = []

    tags = ['love', 'inspirational', 'life', 'humor', 'books', 'reading']
    pages = 3
    url_template = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/{}/page/{}'

    def start_requests(self):

        for tag in self.tags:
            for page in range(self.pages):
                url = self.url_template.format(tag, page)
                yield scrapy.Request(url)


    def parse(self, response):
        # test if method was executed
        print('url:', response.url)

# --- run it without project ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

#c = CrawlerProcess({
#    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
#    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
#    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv',
#}

c = CrawlerProcess()
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```